# Execution of Node.JS code within .NET Core Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, asp.net-core

Code is here.

```
module.exports = function (callback, ID, PATHWAY, CAMPAIGN) {

    var google = require('googleapis');
    var analytics = google.analytics('v3');
    var key = require('JSON PATHWAY');
    var VIEW_ID = 'VIEW ID';

    var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        'SERVICE ACCOUNT', null, key.private_key,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'], null
    );

    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
        console.log('Calling tokens');
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            analytics.data.ga.get({
                'auth': jwtClient,
                'ids': VIEW_ID,
                'metrics': 'ga:pageViews',
                'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday',
                'sort': '-ga:visits',
                'max-results': 100,
                'filters': 'ga:campaign==NAME', 
            }, function (err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    var result = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    callback(/* error */ null, result);
}
```

So above is my Node.JS code.

Here is my Controller Code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestNode([FromServices] INodeServices nodeServices)
{
    var result = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<Object>("./wwwroot/js/GoogleAnalytics", 1, 2, 3);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

All fairly simple and straightforward, apart form when I run it. I get this.

[image: .NET Core Application Error]

So I have checked the following:

- The googleapi is present
- The google.analytics folder and v3 code is present where it should be
- The version of node is up to date
- Node is running
- Node.JS code is running fine (outside of the core).

Comment: Do you have the right version?  You are calling `google.analytics('v3')` but according to this analytics goes away with v4. https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/549#issuecomment-229019835 .  Perhaps you are running version 4?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  good shout and I've just checked on this and there doesn't seem to be a v4 file in the analytics root folder.  I've also change the v3 to be v4 but I still get the same error 'google.analytics is not a function.'  Gotta be something I've missed here.. I hve also noticed that in visual studio under dependencies-npm and you open the tree for the googleapi, it doesn't show the google.analytics.  That anything to do with it?  if so how do you add it or should it show at all?  thanks

Comment: Looking at the source -> `export {analytics_v3} from './apis/analytics/v3';`  so I assume that's what you want to import.

Comment: Looking at the source -> export {analytics_v3} from './apis/analytics/v3'; so I assume that's what you want to import.  IS this done via the console or through the import command in the code file.  ta

Comment: Maybe before calling this through the node services, try running the script directly with Node?

Comment: ok. so ive managed to get it running (I think) but it doesn't return anything in .net core so next steps are to test it in node itself, then go from there.  Incidentally what I did was this....

 var { google } = require('googleapis');
    var analytics = google.analytics('v3');

And it worked!!  I've no idea why or how, or whether it even has...  could anyone shed some light on this maybe?  thanks awfully..